# The fulltext filter daemon host (FDHost) process has stopped abnormally Event 30089

Tags: sql-server-2017, full-text-search

**ENV:  SQL 2017std CU25 8 CPU 48GB mem**

Vendor Software Full Text Catalog setup.

**Found in FT crawler log:**

**A string of these 0x80004005 errors:**

2023-01-27 07:49:02.34 spid19s     Error '0x80004005' occurred during full-text index population for table or indexed view '[tbl_name].[dbo].[tbl_name_121372675]' (table or indexed view ID '278428620', database ID '33'), full-text key value '2685343404782518273'. Attempt will be made to reindex it.

**Followed by:**
2023-01-27 07:49:02.34 spid19s     Informational: Full-text Auto population completed for table or indexed view '[tbl_name].[dbo].[tbl_name_121372675]' (table or indexed view ID '278428620', database ID '33'). Number of documents processed: 61. Number of documents failed: 61. Number of documents that will be retried: 61.
2023-01-27 07:49:02.58 spid38s     A full-text retry pass of Auto population started for table or indexed view '[tbl_name].[dbo].[tbl_name_121372675]'. Table or indexed view ID is '278428620'. Database ID is '33'.

**In Event viewer Application log:**
EVENT ID 30089:  The fulltext filter daemon host (FDHost) process has stopped abnormally. This can occur if an incorrectly configured or malfunctioning linguistic component, such as a wordbreaker, stemmer or filter has caused an irrecoverable error during full-text indexing or query processing. The process will be restarted automatically.

**Tried the following:**

- Switched out default FT service account with Domain Account (local admin permissions)
- Reorganized Fulltext Catalog to decrease fragmentation and updated statistics
- sys.sp_fulltext_service 'ft_timeout'  set to 1200000
- Named Pipes is enabled
- sp_configure 'max full-text crawl range' to 4 (and tried 8)
- Adjusted SQL memory settings per the MS improvement doc (URL below)

What else can I verify/try?  Is there a way to get better details in the logs(debug/verbose)?

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/improve-the-performance-of-full-text-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16]